# What does "localhost:tram" message means?

Tags: linux, rhel, ipv6, lsof

I have deployed an application in Glassfish. I see "localhost:tram" in the list of open files :

```
java 30842 user 1589u IPv6 555599352 0t0 TCP localhost:57171->localhost:tram (CLOSE_WAIT)
java 30842 user 1590u IPv6 555600716 0t0 TCP localhost:57456->localhost:tram (CLOSE_WAIT)
java 30842 user 1591u IPv6 555602019 0t0 TCP localhost:57710->localhost:tram (CLOSE_WAIT)
java 30842 user 1592u IPv6 555603388 0t0 TCP localhost:57985->localhost:tram (CLOSE_WAIT)
java 30842 user 1593u IPv6 555606054 0t0 TCP localhost:58500->localhost:tram (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

What "localhost:tram" message means?

Comment: FWIW, the `tram` port is port 4567. It seems to be associated with routers. Also, the Spark Java framework seems to use this port by default.

Answer (score 2):

When you ran lsof, you did *not* include the `-P` flag, and so it tried to lookup each of the port numbers to translate them to names. This is done via a function call ([`getservbyport`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getservbyport)) through a name service which is configured on Linux via `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. The usual configuration is to point `services` lookups to `file`, which means entries in `/etc/services`.

It's extremely likely, then, that your /etc/services file has this entry:

```
tram            4567/tcp                # TRAM
```

... which you can confirm in various ways, one being: `grep ^tram /etc/services`

You might find it less confusing to use `lsof -P ...` as that will keep the port numbers as numbers. The corresponding flag for hostnames (here, you just have `localhost`) is `-n`.

Port numbers have a central registry, the [Internet Assigned Numbers Authority](https://www.iana.org/), namely the [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml), where you can search for [4567](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=4567).